# How can I create custom metrics in Beam for each value of a particular message attribute?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have an Apache Beam streaming pipeline that runs on Google Cloud Dataflow. Each message that enters the pipeline is a JSON document and contains an eventType attribute. I would like to monitor the number of messages for each value of eventType. (Ultimately I want to display a chart in Google Cloud Monitoring that displays a stacked bar chart of the tally of each eventType.)

I've found the documentation on creating a counter custom metric in Apache Beam: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#types-of-metrics which provides this code:

```java
Counter counter = Metrics.counter( "namespace", "counter1");

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
  // count the elements
  counter.inc();
  //...
}
```

however that code would simply increment a counter for each message in the pipeline, it doesn't provide a counter per eventType which is what I need. Is there a way to count number of messages per eventType?

Comment: Do you know `eventType` before hand? Or does it need to be generated by the element itself?

Comment: The eventType is part of the message (I.e part of the element).

Comment: If you don't know them before hand I don't think you can use metrics. Maybe you could try using Combiners with a GlobalWindow and accumulating elements or StatefulDoFns

Comment: Ah I think I understand your question (i was confused by use of the word "generated"). The domain of possible values for `eventType` is unknown, i.e. there may be `eventType`s in the future that we are not currently aware of.

Comment: "try using Combiners with a GlobalWindow and accumulating elements or StatefulDoFns" Do you know of any links that explain that a little better?

Comment: You can create custom metrics using monitoring client libs.

Hope this helps 

Link [1]: - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#using-custom
Link [2]: - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource
Link [3]: - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#writing-ts

Comment: You can use io.micrometer.core.instrument.Metrics, for example `Metrics.summary(metricName, "evenType", eventType).record(1);` micrometer is abstraction layer and knows to send data to StackDriver, cloudwatch, NewRelic and more

Comment: @Mr.Batra I've read those links, thank you. I think those might do the job.